# VBA to Excel Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

How to make this work? I already tried to reference the sheet/range/column from access to exported excel with ways that I gathered from google but still nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Dim xl As Object
    Dim xlWB As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Dim baseLocation As String
    Const xlMaximized As Long = -4137

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Report_Query", baseLocation, True

    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWB = xl.Workbooks.Open(baseLocation)
    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Worksheets(1)

    xlSheet.Name = tableName
    xlSheet.Columns("A:" & MyModule.outColLetterFromNumber(fSize + 2)).AutoFit


    With xl
        .Rows("2:2").Select
        .ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
        .Rows("1:1").Font.Bold = True
        .Rows("1:1").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        .Rows("1:1").Select
    End With

    With xlSheet
        With .Columns("A:A")
             .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=LEN(TRIM(A1))=0" '//Runtime Error 5 - Invalid Call or Procedure
             .FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                    With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
                    End With
             .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End With

    xl.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlWB.Save
    xl.DisplayAlerts = True
    xl.Visible = True
    xl.DisplayFullScreen = False
    xl.WindowState = xlMaximized

    Set xl = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
```

Comment: I'm not a friend of CF. Before using code to apply CF I would lean over backward trying to use code to apply colors. That looks like the more direct way to me.

Comment: Several issues... but for starters, `Rows` are a property of a worksheet, not an application, so move all those `.Rows` calls currently inside the `With xl` to inside the `With xlSheet` block.

Comment: Also if you're late-binding, you can't use `xlExpression` as that is from the Excel object model, Access doesn't know what that is. Add `Const xlExpression As Long = 2`.

Comment: Hi Big Ben can you also point out other issues? This is my first time for VBA.

Comment: I tried  what you said and now I'm getting the error here `.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority`

Comment: `.FormatConditions(1).SetFirstPriority` since you only have one condition.